# Subclassing QGraphicsRectItem in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am writing an application in which I want to be able to move rectangles by clicking and dragging them. The code below does this correctly so far

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys

class Memory(QWidget):

    grid = None
    scene = None

    def __init__(self, geometry, parent=None):
        super(Memory, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(geometry.x(), geometry.y(), geometry.width(), geometry.height())
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.white)

        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)

        rect = QRectF(40, 40, 220, 110)
        self.make_proxy(rect)

        rect2 = QRectF(300, 40, 220, 110)
        self.make_proxy(rect2)

    def make_proxy(self, rect):

        label = QLabel('World')
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignCenter)

        # create proxy
        proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
        proxy.setWidget(label)
        proxy.setGeometry(rect)
        self.scene.addItem(proxy)

        # create parent item
        rectangle = QGraphicsRectItem(rect)
        rectangle.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.scene.addItem(rectangle)

        # set parent
        proxy.setParentItem(rectangle)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Memory(QRect(10, 10, 550, 180))
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, the first rectangle is always on the bottom of the scene since it was added at first to it. But when I click on it it should go to the top of the scene so that it appears above the second rectangle. This is why I want to subclass `QGraphicsRectItem` and add new features to it. But when I implement it as below

```
class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, rect):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self)
        self.rectangle = rect

    def boundingRect(self):
        super(RectItem, self).boundingRect()
        return self.rectangle
```

and define the `rectangle` variable as

```
        rectangle = RectItem(rect)
```

the items are not movable anymore, i.e. the `QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable` flag has no effect.

Is there a simple way of subclassing `QGraphicsRectItem` and still keep all the convenience functions like `setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)` working?

**EDIT:**

As eyllanesc pointed out it is not necessary to overwrite the `boundingRect` method. Still, when I try to subclass `QGraphicsRectItem` as

```
class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, rect):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self)
```

and define `rectangle` as

```
        rectangle = RectItem(rect)
```

I don't get the same behavior as with

```
        rectangle = QGraphicsRectItem(rect)
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Why are you overwriting boundingRect() ?, could you explain me please.

Comment: I carried it through from another application. But you are right, it is not necessary to overwrite it here.

Comment: With that answer I no longer understand what you want. Can you explain please?

Comment: See the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inherit from a class you must invoke the constructor of the parent and pass some parameters, in your case you use the following:

```
QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self)
```

reviewing the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsrectitem.html):

```
QGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
QGraphicsRectItem(const QRectF &rect, QGraphicsItem *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
QGraphicsRectItem(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
```

You are using the first constructor where you do not have a parent and QRect.

Checking back the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsrectitem.html#details):

> [...] `QGraphicsRectItem` uses the rectangle and the pen width to provide a reasonable implementation of `boundingRect()`, `shape()`, and `contains()`. [...]

From where we see that he uses QRect for `boundingRect()`, and this method is used for other methods like moving, resizing, etc.

For this reason it is not advisable for me to overwrite the parent in this way, in addition to the unintentional, when I overwrite a class I always add information ie new parameters or I set default values to the existing ones, A general way to inherit is the following:

```
class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

If I want to add a parameter, I can use the following template:

```
class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, new_param, *args, **kwargs):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.new_param = new_param
```

or to place a default value:

```
class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, rect=QRect(0, 0, 100,100), parent=parent)
```